# Accessing websites very slowly but good internet

Tags: networking, router, performance, internet

I am accessing a remote computer through Teamviewer and can use it quite quickly without any lag. However, when I try to open a website on the remote computer, it is extremely slow. It is not a permanent issue though but happens for hours a day.

I tried the following to find the problem:

- It happens to almost all websites. The only websites that actually open normally are google and youtube. Other websites do not open at all or open partially. It never loads the entire website. I couldn't even do a speed test since I cannot open the website.
- Teamviewer is quite fast. I don't have any lags at all making me believe that it might not be an internet issue. Uploading files from my computer to the remote one using Teamviewer also works.
- Pinging couple of websites: 0 packages lost and time is around 100ms
- It happens using all browsers.
- I attempted to use opendns or google DNS without any effect.
- Router restart did not have any effect
- Multiple computers face the same problem and so it is not computer related.
- Accessing a website by its IP address also does not work.
- Turning off Windows defender did not work
- ISP says there aren't any problems on their side

It seems to me that the only culprit can be the router but no clue what to check. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you doing the above tests on your local computer or the remote computer.   It would seem to me that the remote computer is having issues (either that or its router, or the Internet connection is being saturated by the outbound traffic that teamviewer is causing).

Comment: At the remote computer through the teamviewer. Any other tests I can do to find the exact reason?

Answer (score -1):

Is this a work environment you TeamView to or is it your home computer you TeamView to?

Does this occur at all when you are physically at that location? You say it happens only sometimes during certain hours or randomly? You could always use your local browser... better refresh rate. However if you are trying to use your remote computer to get around certain Web filters at work... not sure what to tell you.

Comment: Your questions should have been submitted as a comment.  Your inability to submit comments, is not a valid reason, for submitting a comment as an answer.  Please edit this answer, and in specific details, answer the author's question.  If it can't be answered without answers to your question, you should, delete this answer

Comment: It is a work environment (Small business). It happens during certain hours after work, usually 8PM till midnight. then after midnight it returns normally. I don't really need the remote machine to browse, there is an application running on that machine that requires internet connection and it goes offline couple of hours per day due to this problem. I connect through teamviewer to restart it but without any success.